# ngx charts: Line chart define line width

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-charts

I'm using ngxChart for a project, everything is fine, but I just find the line width very thin and I just can't figure out how to get it bigger.

Any help?

Comment: which line. X axis or Yaxis?

Comment: It's on line graph, and it's just the line draw by the graph that I can't set bigger. Not X or Y axis, just the line itself

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the following rule to your global `styles.scss` file:

```css
/* Make lines in line chart thick, with rounded ends */
g.line-chart > g:last-of-type > g:nth-child(n) g.line-series > path {
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

The `n` in `g:nth-child(n)` can be replaced with a number that references the number of the line that you want to modify (e.g. `0` for the first line), or something like `2n` for every second line.

And obviously the width of `10` can be changed to any width.